# How to assign a shader to polygon faces in the maya python api?

Tags: maya

This is what I have so far:

```
m_dest_set_sel = maya.api.OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
m_dest_set_sel.add('lambert4SG')
m_dest_set_obj = m_dest_set_sel.getDependNode(0)
m_dest_set = maya.api.OpenMaya.MFnSet(m_dest_set_obj)

ss = maya.api.OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
ss.add('pCube3.f[2]')
m_dest_set.addMembers(ss)
```

And it gives me this error:

```
# Error: Cannot add the following items to the set since they would break the exclusivity constraint: pCube3.f[2] # 
# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 1: (kFailure): Unexpected Internal Failure #
```

i tried removing it from the "initialShadingGroup" to no avail:

```
m_dest_set_sel = maya.api.OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
m_dest_set_sel.add('initialShadingGroup')
m_dest_set_obj = m_dest_set_sel.getDependNode(0)
m_dest_set = maya.api.OpenMaya.MFnSet(m_dest_set_obj)

ss = maya.api.OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
ss.add('pCube3.f[2]')
m_dest_set.removeMembers(ss)

# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 8: (kInvalidParameter): Cannot find item of required type #
```

Comment: Any reason why you use `maya.api` instead of `maya.cmds`? With maya cmds you can do something like this: `cmds.sets("pCube1.f[4]", edit=True, forceElement="aiStandardSurface1SG")`

Comment: On maya.cmds, assigning thousands of non continous faces (so Maya can't compress the list like pCube1.f[0:5]) takes way more time.

Comment: @MyHornCanPierceTheSky did you have a chance to test the code from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```py
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om2

m_dest_set_sel = om2.MSelectionList()
m_dest_set_sel.add('initialShadingGroup')
m_dest_set_obj = m_dest_set_sel.getDependNode(0)
m_dest_set = om2.MFnSet(m_dest_set_obj)

ss = om2.MSelectionList()
ss.add('pCubeShape1')
m_dest_set.removeMembers(ss)

m_dest_set_sel = om2.MSelectionList()
m_dest_set_sel.add('lambert2SG')
m_dest_set_obj = m_dest_set_sel.getDependNode(0)
m_dest_set = om2.MFnSet(m_dest_set_obj)

ss = om2.MSelectionList()
ss.add('pCube1.f[2]')
m_dest_set.addMembers(ss)
```